# Bing image search in objective c

Tags: objective-c, ios7

I am a novice developer and wanting to add bing image search into my project.so i searched through net and got this link https://github.com/amaechler/AMAImageSearch.But the project is giving me some error like **shell script invocation error**.I don't know how to solve these.Can anyone help me? thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install pod to your project using terminal:

```
rm -rf MyProject.xcworkspace
pod install
```

Comment: I know that this is a poor question; but you are giving a poor answer.  Please put a little more explanation in your answers.